# angular2 and validator - how to pass data to validator

Tags: angular

I have a validator and as a use types I need to test if item is in a array.  Great, I can get the value in the input but how do a pass an array?

```
      mylist = ['a','b']
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){

          this.myForm = this.fb.group({
              slug: ['',[Validators.required,this.validateSlug]],
              description: ['']
          })
      }


validateSlug(control: FormGroup) {
        var valid:any;

        //THIS IF control.value IN mylist
        console.log('dude',control.value);
        valid=true;
        return valid ? null : { validateSlug: true };
   }
```

I cant seem to get access to anything in the validateSlug.

```
 slug: ['',[Validators.required,this.validateSlug(this.items)]],

validateSlug(param1) =>  (control: FormGroup) {
        var valid:any;
        console.log(control.value);

        //let fx = this.items.filter(x => x === control.value)[0];

        valid=true;
        return valid ? null : { validateSlug: true };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getSlugValidator(param1, param2) => 
(control: FormGroup) {
        // param1, param2 are available here

        var valid:any;

        //THIS IF control.value IN mylist
        console.log('dude',control.value);
        valid=true;
        return valid ? null : { validateSlug: true };
   };
```

```
 slug: ['',[Validators.required,this.validateSlug(p1, p2)]],
```

Comment: Where to you get this error? What is the problem with the code you added to your question. What does "I cant seem to get access to anything in the validateSlug" mean? What is "anything"?